# 2 players start with 6 markers. Each round 3 standard dice are rolled. Find the winner of the game and approximate the probability that player 2 wins

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

If the roll is 11, then player 2 gives a marker to player 1, if the roll is 14 player 1 gives a marker to player 2. the first to collect 12 markers wins. The exact probability that player 2 wins is 0.0286. This is what I have so far, but nothing happens when I run it.

```
import random
i = 0
player1 = 6
player2 = 6
rolls = 10000
while player1 != 12 or player2 != 12:
    for i in range(rolls):
        total = random.randint (1,6) + random.randint(1,6) + random.randint (1,6)
        if total == 11:
            player2 = player2 - 1
            player1 = player1 + 1
        if total == 14:
            player1 = player1 - 1
            player2 = player2 +1
        else:
            player1 = player1 + 0
            player2 = player2 + 0            
if player1 == 12:
    print('Player 1 wins')
if player2 == 12:
    print('Player 2 wins')
```

Comment: `for i in range(rolls):` Say each loop takes a microsecond, how long is `rolls` 1000000000000 going to take?

Comment: You'll have to do some debugging one day soon - you could try printing some useful information in each of the paths through your code, so 'nothing happens' becomes perhaps  'some information is printed each time round the loop and I can see counters being passed between playes'..

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop will run as long as at least one player has not 12 tokens.

This is allways the case, as there are only 12 tokens total.

If one hast it the other one has less so your `while player1 != 12 or player2 != 12` is True and it goes round and round.

Try

```
while player1 != 12 and player2 != 12:
```

To limit the game to 10k rounds total, initialize a counter before the while loop, increase it inside the while loop and if the counter goes over 10000: `break` the while loop.

Get rid of the for loop for good it is not needed at all.

---

```
import random
i = 0
player1 = 6
player2 = 6
rolls = 10000
c = 0
while player1 != 12 and player2 != 12 and c < rolls:
    c += 1
    total = random.randint (1,6) + random.randint(1,6) + random.randint (1,6)
    if total == 11:
        player2 = player2 - 1
        player1 = player1 + 1
    if total == 14:
        player1 = player1 - 1
        player2 = player2 +1

if player1 == 12:
    print('Player 1 wins')
if player2 == 12:
    print('Player 2 wins')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I was wondering if you also knew how to get the program to calculate the odds of player 2 winning?